# Gapminder and OurWorldInData

Tags: econometrics, reference-request, statistics

I have found two great resources to learn about the distribution of goods (of any kind) all over the world:

- [gapminder](https://www.gapminder.org/) (Hans Rosling)
- [ourworldindata](http://ourworldindata.org) (Max Roser)

By reading their "about" sections they seem to be quite similar in approach: "Things are not going perfect but better than they seem".

For me it's hard to find out which other providers next to **gapminder** and **ourworldindata** are there around: providing similar access to similar data in a similar way (visual), with a similar (but possibly quite different) approach.

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: I'm confused why you mention "Things are not going perfect but better than they seem." That phrase doesn't add to the question. It seems like a red herring.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not theoretical enough.

Answer (score 1):

On income distribution, there is the [World Inequality Database](https://wid.world/). On poverty, the [World Bank](http://iresearch.worldbank.org/PovcalNet/povOnDemand.aspx) provides lots of comparable figures, although I believe these are the same data as in gapminder.